# Setting Char Code in PDO connection (mysql)

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm having a heck of a time with something simple. Can't seem to get the PDO connection syntax right when I try to connect like I've been doing successfully below but then try to change the charset to UTF-8 (because the apostrophes and quotes in text returned from the db are coming out as symbols)

```
$user='***';
$pass='****';
$hostName='****';
$dataBaseName='****';
$dbh = new pdo('mysql:host='.$hostName.';dbname='.$dataBaseName, $user, $pass);
```

I need to set charset to UTF-8. What is the syntax do add this to my connection without getting errors for every way I have tried so far?

Comment: `$dbh->query("set names 'utf8'");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this :

```
$user='***';
$pass='****';
$hostName='****';
$dataBaseName='****';
$dbh = new pdo('mysql:host='.$hostName.';dbname='.$dataBaseName, $user, $pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
```

I use it and it works for me.